# Magento module default image upload location

Tags: magento

How can I specify the default image upload location for my Magento module (initially made with module creator), *without* having to use `system.xml` for a user configurable option for `<upload_dir/>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an example from the image save functionality used for product attributes - refer to [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Image::afterSave()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Attribute/Backend/Image.php#L44). Pay particular attention to the `Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader` usage.

Carve a niche out for yourself under the *./media/* directory. You might make a class constant or helper for specifying the directory.

Comment: I changed `$model->save();` to `$model->save(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . '/desbest_brands');` and it hasn't ensured that uploads go inside the `media/desbest_brands` folder. Please help.

Comment: You should update your original question with some code snippets and the results which you are seeing. Also, this would be a good motivator to install Xdebug and do step debugging :-)

Comment: I've checked my code again and I got it to work. It turns out that `save()` is mentioned twice in the code under the `saveAction{}` function braces, one being `$media` and another being `$uploader`.

Comment: I might have to steal that one. That's my new catchphrase. ;)